# Prevent submission of a field with the default value

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

i am using the rails 3 UJS for my forms.

In one of the fields, i have the default value as "ABC".

If the user did not change the field, I do not want this value to be submitted.

1) It is an optional field, so i do not want to prevent the form from submitting

2) I could hijack the ":before" action, but that seems hackish to me

This seems like a common use case - what is the most elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to support HTML5-aware browsers, you can use the `placeholder` attribute of the `<input>` tag instead of setting a value you don't want to submit.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="ABC" />
```

Bear in mind that IE9 does not support this attribute ([source](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/inputs.html)).

If you'd rather not, you could use the form's `submit` event to clear the form field if it hasn't been changed.

```
$("#my-form").submit(function(event) {
    var input = $("#my-input-box");
    if (input.val() === "ABC") {
        input.val("");
    }
});
```

You may find that your users sometimes want to type "ABC" into the box. You can solve this by setting a flag when the contents are changed and checking whether the flag is set in the above code instead of comparing the current value to the default.

Comment: Thanks samir! the main issue is that i need to constantly make sure my html and my js is in sync, which is the thing that always leads to bugs

Comment: So tag the inputs with placeholders with a class and just search for that class instead. Then act upon all elements instead of just the one.